# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined when using angular 5 to store data in firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

This is what I have at the moment:

```
createPerson(name:any,lname:any,age:any,dept:any){
  this.peopleList.push({
  name: name,
  lname: lname,
  age: age,
  dept: dept
}).then(_person =>{
  this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
},error=>{console.log(error)});}
```

Comment: check "peopleList" is defined

Comment: yes is defined,and the code is export class AboutPage {
  peopleList : AngularFireList <any>
 
  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public db:AngularFireDatabase ) {
    
   
      this.peopleList = db.list('/people');
      
  };

Answer (score 1):

This syntax seems to be of a promise. A promise can be of type `Promise<any[]>` but that doesn't mean you can use `push()` directly.

In addition, assuming `this.peopleList` is `any[]`, it needs to be initialized before you can do `this.peopleList.push()`.

Finally, it seems you want to do something after `this.peopleList` receives a new item. You should have an observable/promise and do this in two stages. One where it adds to array and returns the array with the new value and then use either `.then` or `.subscribe` to perform the action after the first task is completed.

**Edit:**

```
export interface AngularFireList<T> {
      query: DatabaseQuery;
      valueChanges(events?: ChildEvent[]): Observable<T[]>;
      snapshotChanges(events?: ChildEvent[]): Observable<SnapshotAction<T>[]>;
      stateChanges(events?: ChildEvent[]): Observable<SnapshotAction<T>>;
      auditTrail(events?: ChildEvent[]): Observable<SnapshotAction<T>[]>;
      update(item: FirebaseOperation, data: T): Promise<void>;
      set(item: FirebaseOperation, data: T): Promise<void>;
      push(data: T): database.ThenableReference;
      remove(item?: FirebaseOperation): Promise<void>;
    }
```

This is the AngularFireList interface. From a quick inspection, try something like:

```
// It subscribes to the changes on the list and perform whatever you need upon change. 
// Put it after you initialized the peopleList
this.peopleList.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
   this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
}, error => console.log(error));

// This is adding a new item on the list, which will trigger the subscription above
this.peopleList.push({
  name: name,
  lname: lname,
  age: age,
  dept: dept
});
```

Comment: in this case i did not use push() directly, i already initialized peopleList to AngularFireList<any> and still getting error and you could take a look on my code below...looking forward hear from you////

Comment: the code for initialized the peopleList is= export class AboutPage {
  peopleList : AngularFireList <any>
 
  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public db:AngularFireDatabase ) {
    
   
      this.peopleList = db.list('/people');
      
  };

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr or a repo to see this issue with more clarity? When you debug, what is throwing the undefined?

`this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);` this also needs to be initialized to be pushed. Are they the correct types?